# Visual Studio F12 Hotkey is not working

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I did not understand what happened.
The project suddenly broke down.
F12 does not go with reference!

In the following codes;
While on the yellow field.
I'm clicking on F12.
But it goes to "metadata".

Look at the picture

[image]

I referenced the dll files in the debug folder as references;

[image]

The project was working as usual.
Debug mode is selected everywhere in settings.
I made the project Clean-Build.
I added sildim.
He did not work.

Comment: Delete the references and add them back in as a project reference, don't point to the DLL.

Comment: Remove referenced .ddl's and restart studio, if you have FN button on your keyboard try to press FN+F12, if not, try right click and check what hotkey you see on Reference. Check your hotkeys on VS.

Comment: Super.
Problem solved.
I first deleted the DLLs in the "bin \ debug" folder.
I deleted references from the reference field.
I cleaned up the "Obj" folder.
3 I did the same thing in the project.
Then I cleaned the projects.
I restarted Visual Studio.
I rebuilt my previous project cms.data.
Then I added the second project cms.service to the cms.data reference.
I rebuilt cms.service.
Then I added cms.service and cms.data references to the third project cms.site.
Then I rebuilt the third project.
And start the project :)

Comment: @Oğuzhan SARI, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could post the solution as the answer(Not as a comment), so you could mark it as the answer and help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Thanks for information. I sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super. Problem solved. I first deleted the DLLs in the "bin \ debug" folder. I deleted references from the reference field. I cleaned up the "Obj" folder. 3 I did the same thing in the project. Then I cleaned the projects. I restarted Visual Studio. I rebuilt my previous project cms.data. Then I added the second project cms.service to the cms.data reference. I rebuilt cms.service. Then I added cms.service and cms.data references to the third project cms.site. Then I rebuilt the third project. And start the project :)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other members who get the same issue find the answer easily:)